# Is it possible to have multiple repos in a resolve closure for the Artifactory Gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, build.gradle

I have not been able to resolve against two repositories (ext-releases-local and repo1-cache) on one Artifactory server. My build seems to only resolve against the last repository in the list and ignore the first one. Basically, I have my project's dependencies in ext-releases-local, and their transitive dependencies can be found in the remote repository called repo1-cache. So I need to resolve against both using the Artifactory Gradle plugin. Here is the setup that I have tried in my build.gradle:

```
artifactory {
  contextUrl = "https://myartifactory.host.com"
  publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = "myproj-releases-local"
      username = "${artifactory_deployer_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_deployer_password}"
    }
  }
  resolve {
    repository {
      repoKey = "repo1-cache"
      username = "${artifactory_reader_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_reader_password}"
    }
    repository {
      repoKey = "ext-releases-local"
      username = "${artifactory_reader_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_reader_password}"
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help/advice on getting this to work. There isn't any documentation out on jfrog's website to tell whether resolving to two repos is supported or not. It's definitely possible to do it without the Artifactory Gradle plugin, but unfortunately I will be building via Bamboo, and the Artifactory Gradle plugin has become necessary for release management.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I can tell, this isn't supported. However, you can always create a virtual repository on the Artifactory side that includes `ext-releases-local` and `repo1-cache`. (There is also a predefined virtual repository named `/repo` that includes all repositories.) As a nice side effect, this will likely perform better than declaring two repositories on the Gradle side.

Comment: That's 100% correct answer (@shane, you're welcome to accept and vote). Please only note that using the /repo virtual repository is not advised.

Comment: Thanks so much. I believe the virtual repository `/repo` has everything in it that I need to resolve. I can't seem to retrieve artifacts from it, though. I believe this is a configuration issue: I need to have an admin set **Artifactory Requests Can Retrieve Remote Artifacts** for `/repo`. Just for learning, though, why is resolving to `/repo` not advised -- @JBaruch?

Comment: Using `/repo` is not advised since it defeats the purpose of having different sets of repositories - snapshots vs. staging vs. releases. You can't build a release pipeline by using `/repo`, because everybody can access everything and artifact promotion doesn't make any sense then.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I ended up using one of the pre-canned virtual repos, `libs-release`, to resolve as that contained both the local repository and remote repositories that I needed. Sorry, I am a total noob when it comes to Artifactory. Thanks, again!